# Here maps: Routing - Calculate matrix response shows failed status for few inter combinations of starts to destinations in few countries

Tags: here-api, distance-matrix

Making a Rest call to calculate matrix of HERE routing with multiple starts and destinations but getting proper response only for direct one to one start and destinations and getting status:failed for other inter combinations (getting only for principal diagonal values). Facing the issue only for few countries (here it is India) but working for the samples in the website (Europe)

Rest GET call: `https://matrix.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?apiKey=<API_KEY>&mode=balanced;car;traffic:disabled&summaryAttributes=distance,traveltime&start0=17.251160,78.437737&destination0=16.506174,80.648018&start1=13.069166,80.191391&destination1=12.971599,77.594566`

Response: `{
    "response": {
        "metaInfo": {
            "timestamp": "2020-02-04T12:36:09Z",
            "mapVersion": "8.30.105.150",
            "moduleVersion": "7.2.202005-6333",
            "interfaceVersion": "2.6.75",
            "availableMapVersion": [
                "8.30.105.150"
            ]
        },
        "matrixEntry": [
            {
                "startIndex": 0,
                "destinationIndex": 0,
                "summary": {
                    "distance": 286827,
                    "travelTime": 24236,
                    "costFactor": 24029
                }
            },
            {
                "startIndex": 0,
                "destinationIndex": 1,
                "status": "failed"
            },
            {
                "startIndex": 1,
                "destinationIndex": 0,
                "status": "failed"
            },
            {
                "startIndex": 1,
                "destinationIndex": 1,
                "summary": {
                    "distance": 339029,
                    "travelTime": 26924,
                    "costFactor": 26845
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.Internal team is working on this. We will update you here.

Answer (score 0):

> **The reason behind the observed behaviour is that the road network in
>   India is quite dense, and in some areas the algorithm is not able to
>   find an optimal route within a reasonable time limit.**

We suggest trying out our **[Large Scale Matrix Service](https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/index.html)**. It supports two use cases:

- Matrix Routing calculations with live traffic information for matrices up to 10000x10000 size in a limited size region (up to 400km in diameter).
- Matrix Routing calculations without live traffic information for matrices up to 10000x10000 size without region limitations for fixed sets of parameters (profiles).